# Find code coverage for multi module maven project

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a multi module maven project in one git repository and my integration test cases on another git repository. The output of multi module maven project is three jars for three modules. Now is there a way via command line (so that we can run this through jenkins) to find code coverage for integration tests that are in another repository. The JAR when ran through `java -jar <<jarname>>` it starts a jetty server with the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your jar with JaCoCo agent to gather coverage data - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html

And write a small Ant-script to combine classes, sources and coverage data for generation of report - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html

Note that generation of report requires exact same classes that were used during execution of tests - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html

Comment: Insted of writing the ant script can't I just append all coverage information to a single .exec file using `append=true` argument and let sonar parse that exec file.

Comment: @station SonarQube wasn't mentioned in your question, but yes - you can.